# Hide cat prompt errors

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, cat

I would like to set a script in order to continuously parse a specific marker in a xml file.

The script contains the following `while` loop:

```
function scan_t()
{
INPUT_FILE=${1}
while : ; do
   if [[ -f "$INPUT_FILE" ]]
   then
      ret=`cat ${INPUT_FILE} | grep "<data>" | awk -F"=|>" '{print $2}' | awk -F"=|<" '{print $1}'`
      if [[ "$ret" -ne 0 ]] && [[ -n "$ret" ]]
      then
         ...
      fi
   fi
done
} 
scant_t "/tmp/test.xml"
```

The line format is :

```
<data>0</data> or <data>1</data> <data>2</data> ..
```

Even if the condition `if [[ -f "$INPUT_FILE" ]]` has been added to the script, sometimes I get:

> cat: /tmp/test.xml: No such file or directory.

Indeed, the `$INPUT_FILE` is normally consumed by an other process which is charged to suppress the file after reading.

This `while` loop is only used for test, the `cat` error doesn't matter but I would like to hide this return because it pollutes the terminal a lot.

Comment: This is weird, probably a race condition. To hide such errors, you can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` --> `cat file 2>/dev/null`. Also, not you are saying `cat file | grep | awk | awk`. Probably a simple `awk '...' file` would suffice.

Comment: Thank for your advice, I have exchanged by using `cat file | awk -F '[<,>]' '/data/ {printf "%s ",$3} END {print ""}'`

Comment: Nice! Note `cat file | awk '...'` can be better written as `awk '...' file`.

Comment: Did you try adding quotes like this?: `cat "${INPUT_FILE}"`

Comment: fedorqui, Indeed `awk '...' file` is better but the awk's return is displayed at screen.. In addition, `awk: $INPUT_FILE: No such file or directory` is returned.

Comment: j.a, yes I have tried by using `cat "${file}" | awk '...'` but the result is still the same.

Comment: A commentary: To reply to users, use the `@` symbol (e.g.: @SnP)

Comment: It is weird you are getting "awk: $INPUT_FILE: No such file or directory". The `$INPUT_FILE` should be expanded and get the content of it instead.

Comment: @fedorqui: I was assuming that wasn't the literal output, and he'd edited `cat`'s error message to keep the implementation-details out of the question.  (Like you guys, I did find it *more* confusing, not less, to see a `$var` in a supposed error message.  Please edit the question to clear up that confusion, SnP.)

Comment: Sorry guys, Peter Cordes is right. I edited the `cat`'s error message manually. I should have avoided that.. The first post has been updated.

Comment: That's true @Peter, comment deleted.

Answer (score 4):

If some other process can also read and remove the file before this script sees it, you've designed your system with a race condition.  (I assume that "charged to suppress" means "designed to unlink"...)

If it's optional for this script to see every input file, then just redirect stderr to `/dev/null` (i.e. ignore errors when the race condition bites).  If it's not optional, then have this script rename the input file to something else, and have the other process watch for *that*.  Check for that file existing before you do the rename, to make sure you don't overwrite a file the other process hasn't read yet.

---

Your loop has a horrible design.  First, you're busy-waiting (with no `sleep` at all) on the file coming into existence.  Second, you're running 4 programs when the input exists, instead of 1.

The busy-wait can be avoided by using `inotifywait` to watch the directory for changes.  So the `if [[ -f $INPUT_FILE ]]` loop body only runs after a modification to the directory, rather than as fast as a CPU core can run it.

The second is simpler to address: never `cat file | something`.  Either `something file`, or `something < file` if `something` doesn't take filenames on its command line, or behaves differently.  `cat` is only useful if you have multiple files to concatenate.  For reading a file into a shell variable, use `foo=$(<file)`.

I see from comments you've already managed to turn your whole pipeline into a single command.  So write

```
INPUT_FILE=foo;
inotifywait -m -e close_write -e moved_to --format %f . |
while IFS= read -r event_file;do
    [[ $event_file == $INPUT_FILE ]] &&
       awk -F '[<,>]' '/data/ {printf "%s ",$3} END {print ""}' "$INPUT_FILE" 2>/dev/null

     #  echo "$event_file" &&
     #  date;
done
# tested and working with the commented-out echo/date commands
```

Note that I'm waiting for close_write and moved_to, rather than other events, to avoid jumping the gun and reading a file that's not finished being written.  Put `$INPUT_FILE` in its own directory, so you don't get false-positive events waking up your loop for other filenames.

To also implement the rename-to-input-for-next-stage suggestion, you'd put a `while [[ -e $INPUT2 ]]; do sleep 0.2; done; mv -n "$INPUT_FILE" "$INPUT2"` busy-wait loop after the awk.

---

An alternative would be to run `inotifywait` once per loop iteration, but that has the potential for you to get stuck with `$INPUT_FILE` created before `inotifywait` started watching.  So the producer would be waiting for the consumer to consume, and the consumer wouldn't see the event.

```
# Race condition with an asynchronous producer, DON'T USE
while inotifywait -qq -e close_write -e moved_to; do
    [[ $event_file == $INPUT_FILE ]] &&
       awk -F '[<,>]' '/data/ {printf "%s ",$3} END {print ""}' "$INPUT_FILE" 2>/dev/null
done
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the name of a file that doesn't exist yet, even as a filter, so the loop body needs to test for the specific file existing in the dir before using.

---

If you don't have inotifywait available, you could just put a `sleep` into the loop.  GNU sleep supports fractional seconds, like `sleep 0.5`.  Busybox probably doesn't.  You might want to write a tiny trivial C program anyway, which keeps trying to `open(2)` the file in a loop that includes a `usleep` or `nanosleep`.  When `open` succeeds, redirect stdin from that, and `exec` your `awk` program.  That way, there's no race possible between a `stat` and an `open`.

```
#include <unistd.h>    // for usleep/dup2

#include <sys/types.h>  // for open
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // for perror

void waitloop(const char *path)
{
    const char *const awk_args[] = { "-F", "[<,>]",
         "/data/ {printf \"%s \",$3} END {print \"\"}",
         path
    };
    while(42) {
        int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
        if (-1 != fd) {
            // if you fork() here, you can avoid the shell loop too.

            dup2(fd, 0);  // redirect stdin from fd.  In theory should check for error here, too.
            close(fd);   // and do this in the parent after fork
            execv("/usr/bin/awk", (char * const*)awk_args);  // execv's prototype doesn't prevent it from modifying the strings?
        } else if(errno != ENOENT) {
            perror("opening the file");
        } // else ignore ENOENT
        usleep(10000);  // 10 milliseconds.
    }

}
// optional TODO: error-check *all* the system calls.
```

This compiles, but I haven't tested it.  Looping inside a single process doing `open` / `usleep` is much lighter weight than running a whole process to do `sleep 0.01` from a shell.

Even better would be to use inotify to watch for directory events to detect the file appearing, instead of `usleep`.  To avoid a race, after setting up the inotify watch, do another check for the file existing, in case it got created after your last check, but before the inotify watch became active.

Comment: The rewrite is obviously a substantial improvement, but you might note that using `cat` is not only [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html); if you used `grep` to read the file directly, you could have simply suppressed the error message with `-s`.

Comment: Thank you Peter for these informations, it's quite interesting !! But I should have mentionned that I am working on a Embedded platform and its distribution is created by using Yocto. The inotify-tools package is currently not included into the file system. Because the package is not defined into poky or meta-oe layers I am not able to add it, even if I know how to do that..

Comment: In addition you said `"then have this script rename the input file to something else"` and `"Check for that file existing before you do the rename"`. Howerver if a `mv` is performed after `if [[ -f "$INPUT_FILE" ]]` the prompt error will be just exchanged to `mv : No Such File or Directory`, will not ?

Comment: @SnP: If you have the other consumer of `$INPUT_FILE` waiting for a different name, it won't steal input files from this script.  Redirecting `mv`'s stderr to discard error messages shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @SnP: custom-build inotifywait for your embedded platform, or use the inotify system call from perl (or some other language you're already using), or from a custom C program.  It's not like `inotifywait` has an ideal command-line interface for this use-case anyway.  Busy-waiting on the file to show up is an even worse idea on a single-core embedded platform.  Even if wasting most of your CPU time isn't a performance problem, it will make your device run hotter than it would otherwise.

Comment: @SnP: I updated my answer with some more suggestions, including a wait-loop written in C.